# Java synchronized on local variable illustration

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

This is a method source code from apache zookeeper,class DataTree

```
 /**
 * update the count of this stat datanode
 *
 * @param lastPrefix
 *            the path of the node that is quotaed.
 * @param diff
 *            the diff to be added to the count
 */
public void updateCount(String lastPrefix, int diff) {
    String statNode = Quotas.statPath(lastPrefix);
    DataNode node = nodes.get(statNode);
    StatsTrack updatedStat = null;
    if (node == null) {
        // should not happen
        LOG.error("Missing count node for stat " + statNode);
        return;
    }
    synchronized (node) {
        updatedStat = new StatsTrack(new String(node.data));
        updatedStat.setCount(updatedStat.getCount() + diff);
        node.data = updatedStat.toString().getBytes();
    }
    // now check if the counts match the quota
    String quotaNode = Quotas.quotaPath(lastPrefix);
    node = nodes.get(quotaNode);
    StatsTrack thisStats = null;
    if (node == null) {
        // should not happen
        LOG.error("Missing count node for quota " + quotaNode);
        return;
    }
```

...

My question is why it synchronized on the node object? If other thread remove the node from nodes which is a HashMap, then node becomes invalid. Is there some problem here?

Comment: I would assume it's because they want `node.data` to be updated atomically.  If two threads hit this critical section together, the stats may be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is why it synchronized on the node object?

`node` is acting as a synchronization object. It is quite common for threads to synchronize on an object whose internal states can be modified by some of these threads. This synchronization imposes an ordering among threads. Thus race conditions are avoided. Your code does not show it but there may be other parts of the project where the contents of `node` are modified by other threads. As a result, all threads which synchronize on `node` will be consistent.

> If other thread remove the node from nodes which is a HashMap, then node becomes invalid. Is there some problem here?

If `node` is removed from the hashmap, it does not mean that the node will be invalid. It will not be destroyed by garbage collector either because it is referenced in the code you have shown.

`node` will be invalid only when no longer referenced in the whole program.

Comment: Could you please explain what will happe if the node is removed by  other thread before it comes into synchronized(node) ?

Comment: @andy what do you mean by 'removed'? I suppose your code returns null already in that case and the critical section will not be executed because you have a return statement: 
    if (node == null) {
        // should not happen
        LOG.error("Missing count node for stat " + statNode);
        return; // <- should return here.
    }

Comment: I mean the node is removed from the nodes hashmap, the problem is if node is got before removed ,it can come into critical seciton

Answer (score 1):

> My question is why it synchronized on the node object?

It *seems* strange to synchronize on a local, but note that the local's value is coming from outside the function (`nodes`, which is probably an instance member). So the object it's synchronizing on will be available to multiple threads, and clearly the code in that method needs to be sure that it isn't being run concurrently on more than one thread for the same `node`.

In this case, clearly it's protecting the update of `node.data`, and for good reason: It's taking `node.data`, modifying that data, then updating `node.data` with the result. Two threads doing that at the same time could stomp on each other's work.

> If other thread remove the node from nodes which is a HashMap, then node becomes invalid.

No, it just isn't in the HashMap anymore. Removing it from the map doesn't modify the node.